# Using VeinsInetMobility and TraCIMobility

Tags: omnet++, veins

Is that possible for a node to be both VeinsInetMobility and TraCIMobility? If so how?

Comment: In theory, yes, this can be built in Veins - thus allowing you to use both set of a radio channels simulated by Veins and a fully independent set of radio channels simulated by INET. I don’t see a particularly pressing reason to do that, though. Can you elaborate on why you would want to do that?

Comment: So the idea is that I want to use planned road ids from the Vehicle class in TraciMobility in order to route data effectively. I believe Veins_Lte uses TraciMobility, but I rather not use it as it is very buggy.  So i was wondering if there is an easy way to obtain planned road ids of in Simulte_Veins, either by having nodes use TraciMobility or by another method

Answer (score 1):

As you did not specify software versions, I am assuming Veins 5a1 with its `veins_inet` subproject, INET 4.0.0, and SUMO 1.1.0. Getting the list of planned road IDs is simple then: just use the methods of `VeinsInetMobility` - no need to use two mobility modules.

For example, in [`VeinsInetSampleApplication`](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-5a1/subprojects/veins_inet/src/veins_inet/VeinsInetSampleApplication.cc#L83) you can use it to directly call functions from [`TraCICommandInterface`](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-5a1/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCICommandInterface.h#L124) like so: `traciVehicle->getPlannedRoadIds()` (similar to the code shown [here](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-5a1/subprojects/veins_inet/src/veins_inet/VeinsInetSampleApplication.cc#L83)).

If you are using INET 3 via `veins_inet3`, you may simply adapt the functions of `veins_inet` for this project to do the same.